# WCF Server without administrator permissions

Tags: wcf, security, ws-security

I have an application, which exposes a web serice via wsHttpBinding. From [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/5273c0ee-15ae-4327-bf9e-b8da10cffc47/), I understand that I can not run it unless I am a server administrator. Is that seriously so?

Does anyone here know if I can grant the account only specific rights to enable him run WCF service, and not make account full administrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitlale/archive/2007/01/29/addressaccessdeniedexception-cause-and-solution.aspx